# How do I represent my joins in Relational Algebra?

Tags: sql, database, relational-algebra

I am new to relational algebra and for my assignment I have to create two. I have written out the problem I have faced in SQL but I am unsure of how to represent such joins in relational algebra. Any help/pointers would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT ps.FirstName AS StudentFirstName, ps.LastName AS StudentLastName, pst.FirstName AS StaffFirstName , pst.LastName AS StaffLastName, pg.FirstName AS GuardianFirstName, pg.LastName AS GuadianLastName, i.DateTimeReported, i.NatureOfIllness
FROM Incident i
JOIN Student s USING (StudentID)
JOIN Person ps ON (s.StudentID = ps.PersonID)
JOIN Staff st USING (StaffID)
JOIN Person pst ON (st.StaffID = pst.PersonID)
JOIN Guardian g USING (GuardianID)
JOIN Person pg ON (g.GuardianID = pg.PersonID)
WHERE i.DecisionMade IS NULL;
```

Comment: I have a feeling your database design is really awkward to work with

Answer (score 2):

Those left joins you're doing are referred to in relational algebra as theta-joins, sometimes more specifically specifically as equijoins. You'll want to use the symbol that looks like a bow tie and write "StudentID = PersonID" underneath it (for the second join in your example). I can't do the fancy symbols, but http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#.CE.B8-join_and_equijoin has some examples.

Also, there's nothing wrong with 6-way joins and they'll indeed happen in the real world.

Comment: I was under the impression that an 'inner join' was an 'equi-join'

Answer (score -4):

I think you are going about the problem the wrong way. In the real world you'd never want to create a situation where you had a 6 way join.

What it seems like you have here are incidents and people. The people have roles. There should be maybe three tables, incidents, roles, and people. The way you're joining against Person twice, is going to be a mess.

I think you should sit down and read about database normalization.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: The reason I have joined the person table multiple times is because of i am using database inheritance where the common values are stored in the person table and all person type specifics are stored in their own tables.

Comment: @rabble: in the real world more than 6 joins occurrs so frequently I would call it the norm (so I would suspect you hae little real world experience). You also mention database normalization (which is a good thing) but fail to notice that it tends to increase joins.

Comment: Normalized databases don't scale. I build fireeagle.com and odeo.com... At load you can't do joins, it's just the reality. It's why there is so much interest right now in alternatives to RDMS...